# Scattering. could a particle by an almost specific momentum hit a microscopic target?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, scattering, scattering-cross-section

In describing scattering processes some authors (e.g. Susskind in video lectures) say: a particle with a specific momentum hits the target and then scatters off. But I think Heisenberg's principle force such a particle not to have such locality that could aimed to such a target.

May be you say Planck's constant in Heisenberg principle is too small and so we have locality and specific momentum mutually. but if Heisenberg's principle don't show off itself in such a quantumic process then where?

Is answer is coming particle is somehow a cloud thin but after aiming target by many of this clouds some of them by a somehow bizarre (quantum) phenomenon hit the target?

Answer (score 0):

Usually when we start learning scattering we start with classical scattering which is a particle hitting another particle and scatter off. However, in Quantum scattering theory is studied as waves.[image]

In the image you can see that we have an incoming wave with momentum $k$ and we get spherical scattering wave about the point of scattering. These waves are not localised as per the Heisenberg's uncertainty principle, but the incoming wave can scatter due to some potential at the point of scattering. For large $r$, the solution will look like,
$$\psi(r,\theta)\approx A\big(e^{ikz}+f(\theta)\frac{e^{ikr}}{r}\big)$$
Further we use partial wave analysis and Born approximation to solve Schrodinger's equation for $\psi(r,\theta)$ to find out $f(\theta)$ and scattering amplitude.

Comment: This answer describes an incoming state of specific momentum but OP was wondering why that is possible so I'm not sure it answers his question. Though I consider it an excellent and helpful answer nonetheless. I'm no expert, but from what I understood in the scattering section of my QFT class, the "exact momentum state" is only a theoretical idealization, and the real states would have some spread in momentum. Depending on what is being calculated, this can make a difference, and it "has been done" that gaussian states with approximate momentum are considered instead.

Comment: Using gaussian states of low width rather than perfect eigenstates is claimed to give the same results to good approximation, and now the states satisfy the uncertainty principle. However, I should note that even a perfect eigenstate doesn't necessarily violate the HUP. The product of 0 with $\infty$ is just undefined, but isn't necessarily less than $\hbar/2$, and if you express that product as a limit of gaussian states, the limiting standard deviations never violate the HUP, so no problem. But there are other reasons to believe that perfect eigenstates of $x$ or $p$ are unphysical.

Comment: I think your note is related to my 2th paragraph in which predicted such an answer and said I have a problem with it. my problem was if we refer to incredible smallness of $\hbar$ and say so HUP doesn't cause any problem here then I infer $\hbar$ is so small that at current time (by current laboratories) we have no experiment to detect it: as currently we can't make any decision about point or string nature of elementary particles because they size is of order of $\hbar$ @doublefelix